# "No results found" with specific dimensions in Google Analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a code that get some data using some querys in Google Analytics (java). I usually check the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to know how the data will be printed, the range of values, etc.

My problem appears when I set a query with 6 dimensions (for example) and the result using the Query explorer is 0 results showed. Using my code it displays "No result found". 
However, when I remove one dimension (always user gender or user age) the query works without problems.

I want query all my 6 dimensions filtering the problematic dimension in some way that allows me to display the other data.

For example, let's say that when I insert the dimensionX in the query the results is: "No results found"

I want to filter something like (`ga:dimensionX==empty` or `null`) to display and perform the query without changing my dimensions in it.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

**Edit:**

Here there is some code about my failed query:

```
private static GaData getIds(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga()
            .get("ga:" + profileId, "7daysAgo", "today", "ga:users")
            .setDimensions("ga:countryIsoCode, ga:userGender, ga:cityId, ga:city")
            .setSort("-ga:countryIsoCode")
            .execute();
}
```

The result is: "No results found". Using the Query Explorer this not display any result. However, when I remove `ga:userGender` the query works perfect. In this case, `ga:userGender` is my problematic dimension, but in other queries it happens with others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the data isn't there then Google analytics isn't going to return it.  Google analytics doesn't work like a relational database you cant just select values and get nulls for columns with not data.   If there is no data you just get nothing for the result set.

Comment: That is what I've read. But then why when I put some dimensions it does not return any value? @DaImTo

Comment: Because some dimensions and metrics do have data together.  There are others where the data wasn't recorded for some reason so the data isn't there.   What is your exact query I may be able to shed some light on why there is no data for it.

Comment: Question edited @DaImTo. In this case, the user gender is what makes fail my query but in the other cases is my custom dimension

Comment: ga:userGender is one of the double click dimensions my bet is its not always going to be there.  This will be especially true for an account that hasn't enabled Enable Demographics and Interest Reports properly or not at all https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad

Comment: as for your custom dimension if your not sending it on every single request to Google then your going to be missing data there as well.  I mean every request.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for answering